# Schema.org for marking up degree program, or educational tracks

Tags: schema.org

I'm trying to represent a list of education programs that students can enroll in. Each program consists of a set of courses and has its own URL and page listing all the individual courses.

I was planning to use the `Course` specification to markup the list of courses for each track, but I'm having trouble understanding the best way to represent the list of programs.

Should they be listed as `Product`s, or should I reuse the `Course` specs, even though it represents a set of courses? Any opinions on which option might give better search engine visibility?

Answer (score 0):

try something like the following.

you can add Courses and their description to ListItem/Service.

those Courses then can be marked-up using CourseInstance.

The following can be implemented as a `@graph` but its easier to maintain, improve and reuse as linked items.

```
<script type="application/ld+json" id="14310000001001">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Service",
    "@id": "14310000001001",
    "name": "xxx engineering education",
    "description": "Teaching the content of xxx Engineering",
    "logo": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "@id": "12170302151001"
    },
    "releaseDate": "",
    "category": {
        "@type": "Thing",
        "@id": "https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/xxx"
    },
    "provider": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "@id": "16020000001001"
    },
    "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "@id": "14180000001001"
    },
    "hasOfferCatalog": {
        "@type": "OfferCatalog",
        "@id": "1414020000xxxx"
    },
    "audience": {
        "@type": "Audience",
        "@id": "http://www.bls.gov/soc/22032500001567"
    }
}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json" id="14180000001001">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Offer",
    "@id": "14180000001001",
    "itemOffered": {
        "@type": "Service",
        "@id": "14310000001001"
    },
    "priceSpecification": {
        "@type": "PriceSpecification",
        "price": "0",
        "minPrice": "0",
        "maxPrice": "0",
        "priceCurrency": "USD"
    },
    "offeredBy": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "@id": "17000000001009"
    }
}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json" id="1414020000xxxx">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "OfferCatalog",
    "@id": "1414020000xxxx",
    "name": "Education Service Catalog",
    "description": "",
    "itemListOrder": "http://schema.org/ItemListOrderAscending",
    "numberOfItems": "3",
    "itemListElement": [{
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": "1",
        "item": {
            "@type": "Service",
            "@id": "14310000001001"
        }
    },
    {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": "2",
        "item": {
            "@type": "Service",
            "@id": "14310000001002"
        }
    },
    {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": "3",
        "item": {
            "@type": "Service",
            "@id": "14310000001003"
        }
    }]
}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json" id="Qxxxxxxx">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Thing",
    "@id": "https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/xxx",
    "name": "xxx engineering",
    "description": "",
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/xxx",
    "sameAs": "http://dbpedia.org/page/xxx"
}
</script>
```